# How can a java application running within a Fargate container connect to Aurora Postgresql db?

Tags: terraform, containers, amazon-aurora, aws-fargate, dbconnect

We have a java application running in a Fargate container and this application needs to connect and have limited access to the Aurora Postgesql DB.

How can this java application connect to Aurora Postgres DB?

I thought of creating a user account within the db and assigning policies but I need this to be done using Terraform.

Is my approach right? if yes how do we create a user account in Aurora Postgresql db using Terraform.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have created a database user and attached rds-db:connect policy to ECS Tasks. Now I want the Fargate container to use this user to connect to the Aurora Postgresql DB. Also I don't want to manually connect using AWS CLI, I want the aws authentcation taken to be generated automatedly. How can this be done?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask